# Undefined array key "REMOTE_ADDR" in laravel octane

Tags: laravel, octane

I am using laravel 8. Before upgarding to octane I was getting ip address in $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. After changing to octane there is no such index in $_SERVER.

I am using  this variable in validator of register controller ,while new  user is registering to app.

```
 protected function validator(array $data)
      {
 dd($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
}
```

when I dump $_SERVER I am getting this array (I am hiding app details.)

```
  "LARAVEL_OCTANE" =>"1"
  "APP_BASE_PATH" => "xxx"
  "JOURNAL_STREAM" => "xxx"
  "PATH" =>"xxx"
  "INVOCATION_ID" => "xxx"
  "LANG" => "xxx"
  "SUPERVISOR_ENABLED" =>"xxx"
  "SUPERVISOR_SERVER_URL" => "xxx"
  "SUPERVISOR_PROCESS_NAME" =>"xxx"
  "APP_ENV" => "xxx"
  "PWD" => "xxx"
  "PHP_SELF" => "xxx"
  "SCRIPT_NAME" => "xxx"
  "SCRIPT_FILENAME" =>"xxx"
  "PATH_TRANSLATED" => "xxx"
  "DOCUMENT_ROOT" => ""
  "REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT" => "xxx"
  "REQUEST_TIME" => "xxx"
  "argv" => array:2 [▶]
  "argc" =>"xxx"
  "APP_NAME" => "xxx"
  "APP_KEY" => "xxx"
  "APP_DEBUG" => "xxx"
  "APP_LOG_LEVEL" => "xxx"
  "APP_URL" => "xxx"
  "OCTANE_SERVER" =>"xxx"
  "LOG_CHANNEL" => "xxx"
  "DB_CONNECTION" => "xxx"
  "DB_HOST" => "xxx"
  "DB_PORT" => "xxx"
  "DB_DATABASE" => "xxx"
  "DB_USERNAME" =>"xxx"
  "DB_PASSWORD" => "xxx"
  "BROADCAST_DRIVER" => "xxx"
  "CACHE_DRIVER" => "xxx"
  "SESSION_DRIVER" => "xxx"
  "SESSION_LIFETIME" => "xxx"
  "QUEUE_CONNECTION" => "xxx"
  ...............
```

Comment: You would be better off using the `Request` class for this. Please can you show the code where you're actually trying to access the value and any related route/controller code.

Comment: Are you serving your page directly or going via a proxy?

Comment: thanks for response @Rwd , I have added more details in question .I am using this code inside validator

Comment: @apokryfos thanks for responding .I am  not using proxy .I am using google  reCAPTCHA v3 in my register page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution for this problem. As @Rwd commented
replaced
`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` by `request()->ip()`

and it works correctly .
(In octane the global variables of PHP will not be initialized when the request is initialized, such as$_ SERVER, $_ POST, $_ Get, etc.. Got details from following article. https://developpaper.com/php-fpm-vs-swoole/)